# Uable to setText on EditText in dialogbox

Tags: android, kotlin, settext

I have a method `showDownloadDialog()` called in `onOptionsItemSelected` that presents a dialog box with `EditText`. I wish to set this value from `SharePreferences`. However the `.setText()` does not display the string value from `SharePreferences`.
The toast displays the correct string value. Appreciate anyone who encountered this problem can show me the right path. Many thanks

```
 private fun showDownloadDialog() {
        val sharePreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedString : String? = sharePreferences.getString("STRING_KEY", null)
        var gameToDownload: String

        Toast.makeText(this, "Prefer string v3 = $savedString, length ${savedString!!.length}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val boardDownloadView = LayoutInflater.from( this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_download_board, null)

        showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.fetchMemoryGame), boardDownloadView, View.OnClickListener {
            // Grab the text of the game name that the user wants to download
            val etDownGame = boardDownloadView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etDownloadGame)
           
                etDownGame.setText(savedString)
```

The xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDownloadGame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:digits="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enterGameName"
        android:text=""
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert from `String` to `Editable` directly , use

```
private fun String.toEditable(): Editable =  
    Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(this)
```

in your activity as utility function and apply as

```
etDownGame.setText(savedString.toEditable())
```

Comment: Many thanks @Anshul. I implemented your suggestion but still not getting the value (i.e saveString "test15") to the editText. It is still show the hint instead of the string value "test15)

Comment: Try using `etDownGame.text = savedString.toEditable()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Anshul. It works after moving etDownGame out of showAlertDialog. Although I still unsure why setText() does not work inside showAlertDialog.

```
private fun showDownloadDialog() {
        val sharePreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedString : String? = sharePreferences.getString("STRING_KEY", null)
        var gameToDownload: String

        Toast.makeText(this, "v8 savedString = $savedString, length ${savedString!!.length}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val boardDownloadView = LayoutInflater.from( this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_download_board, null)
        val etDownGame = boardDownloadView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etDownloadGame)
        if (savedString!!.isNotEmpty()) {
            etDownGame.setText(savedString)
        }

showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.fetchMemoryGame), boardDownloadView, View.OnClickListener {
            // Grab the text of the game name that the user wants to download
            //val etDownGame = boardDownloadView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etDownloadGame)
    

            gameToDownload = etDownGame.text.toString().trim()

                downloadGame(gameToDownload)
        })
    }
```